# Wordpress CSS, Setting margin to zero is not working

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to set the margin for a div tag to zero using CSS. This is the link to the site:

http://jtech-online.com/

This is  the margin I am trying to set to zero:
[image]

I've tried all of these but its not working:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 620px) {
     div.builder-container {
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-device-width: 620px) {
    div.builder-container-outer-wrapper div.builder-container {
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-device-width: 620px) {
    div.builder-container-background-wrapper div.builder-container-outer-wrapper div.builder-container {
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

Apparently its not recognizing the selector. Any Ideas?

Additional Notes: It works fine when its outside the media query for all sizes:

```
 div.builder-container {
    margin:0;
}
```

Additional Note 2: As you can see in the picture below there is margin when I specified there shouldn't be any:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried them using `!important`? Like `.builder-container-outer-wrapper {
    max-width: 100% !important;
}`

Comment: @IkoTikashi nope, still not working.

Comment: add style `min-width:100%;` to the class `.builder-container-outer-wrapper`

Comment: Nope, didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I found the answer, it should have been:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 620px) {
     div.builder-container {
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

max-width not max-device-width